# Replace string using wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL

Have a table containing data like 'SeqXXXX: hello world'

The XXXX of course being incremented numbers.

I would like to replace those with a blank. Is there a way to replace 'Seq' + 4 to the right with a blank in an update statement?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use (the available string functions may differ) and is the pattern always exactly `SeqXXXX`, exactly 4 characters following `'Seq'`? Finally when you say you want to replace them with a blank, do you mean 4 empty strings so the total length is still 7, or remove them so the total length is 3?

Comment: Sorry MS SQL and the pattern will always be the same

Comment: @MainMa haha sorry it's Monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = 'Seq'
WHERE LEN(YourColumn) = 7 AND
      PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',RIGHT(YourColumn,4)) = 1 AND 
      LEFT(YourColumn, 3) = 'Seq'
```

As per your comment, alter it as below

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 8, LEN(YourColumn))
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',RIGHT(LEFT(YourColumn, 7),4)) = 1 AND 
      LEFT(YourColumn, 3) = 'Seq'
```

Comment: isn't working correctly with 'Seq0001 Hello World' I removed LEN since the length can vary but the column will always start with 'SeqXXXX' I want to remove 'SeqXXXX' and leave the rest

Answer (score 1):

This will change

```
Seq1234: hello world
```

Into

```
: hello world
```

-

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourcolumn = stuff(yourcolumn, 1,7,'')
WHERE yourcolumn like 'seq[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: I haven't actually seen anyone use STUFF before. I like it and is easier to read. Do you know which would be better for performance? Kaf's post or yours? I also changed it to the following to remove the need for RegEx

update @Workspace set test= STUFF(test, 1, 9, '') WHERE test like 'Seq%'

Comment: @Tsukasa the stuff and substring would be same performance more or less. The where clause in my example would be faster. Logic is not the same though, my logic requires 4 digits, his logic only the first. I didnt expect you needed the last 2 characters. But i wanted to give you an answer to your question without secondguessing

Comment: So it would be better to include the regex in the where rather than just Seq?

Comment: @Tsukasa for performance, readability and logic yes. RIGHT(LEFT('Seq1234', 7),4) will return 1234. Other script is just asking if the first character of 1234 is a number with a very complicated calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can also use replace function with Patindex to trim off the digits.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188395.aspx